# не создается файл и не записываются значения. в чем проблема?

Tags: c++, файлы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
long double eccentricity = 0.5220019945150835;
const long double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
int period = 28080; //c
double apoсenter_radius_vector = 12389.5; //km
double periapsis_radius_vector = 3654.5; //km
long double calculateEccentricAnomaly(long double eccentricity, long double mean_anomaly, long double precision) {
    long double E0 = mean_anomaly;
    long double diff = 0.001;
    int max_iterations = 10000;
    int iteration = 0;
    while (diff > precision && iteration < max_iterations) {
        long double E1 = mean_anomaly + eccentricity * sin(E0);
        diff = std::abs(E1 - E0);
        E0 = E1;
        iteration++;
    }
    return E0;
}

long double calculateTrueAnomaly(long double eccentricity, long double eccentric_anomaly) {
    long double true_anomaly = 2 * atan(sqrt((1 + eccentricity) / (1 - eccentricity)) * tan(eccentric_anomaly / 2));
    return true_anomaly;
}

int main() {
    // расчет массы марса
    double mass = exp(24 * log(0.642) + log(10));
    double gravitational_constant = exp(-11 * log(6.67) + log(10));
    return 0;

    // расчет гравитационного параметра
    long double gravitational_parametr;
    gravitational_parametr = mass * gravitational_constant;


    long double major_axis;
    //расчет главной полуоси
    major_axis = (apoсenter_radius_vector + periapsis_radius_vector) / 2;

    long double eccentricity;
    // расчет эксцентриситета 
    eccentricity = (apoсenter_radius_vector / major_axis) - 1;

    long double focal_parameter;
    // Расчет фокального параметра
    focal_parameter = major_axis * (1 - eccentricity * eccentricity);

    // Вывод результата
    std::cout << "а: " << major_axis << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e: " << eccentricity << std::endl;
    std::cout << "p: " << focal_parameter << std::endl;

    return 0;


    long double precision = 1e-10;
    std::ofstream fout("result.txt");
    fout.open("result.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
    //std::ofstream out("results.txt"); // Open the file for writing

    for (int time = 0; time <= 28080; time++) {
        long double mean_anomaly = 2 * PI * time / 28080;
        long double eccentric_anomaly = calculateEccentricAnomaly(eccentricity, mean_anomaly, precision);
        long double true_anomaly = calculateTrueAnomaly(eccentricity, eccentric_anomaly);

        fout << time << " " << eccentric_anomaly << " " << true_anomaly << std::endl; // Write the results to the file
    }

    fout.close(); // Close the file
    std::cout << "File has been written" << std::endl;
    system("pause")
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в main() три `return 0;`, зачем? Вы ведь по сути отсекаете любой код, который после них записан.

В строке `std::ofstream fout("result.txt");` вы уже открыли файл для записи, вам его не нужно повторно открывать...

И лучше переменную `time` в файл не записывать, ибо номер строки в которой расположжен ваш вывод и является переменной `time`. Просто, когда будете считывать результат, создайте какую-нибудь переменную `i` и она будет вашим счётчиком, а так вы только дополнительное место в файле занимаете.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

/* Это куда??? */
// long double eccentricity = 0.5220019945150835;
/* ??? */

const int PERIOD = 28080;
const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
const double PERIAPSIS_RADIUS_VECTOR = 3654.5; //km
const double APOCENTER_RADIUS_VECTOR = 12389.5; //km

double calculateEccentricAnomaly(double eccentricity, double mean_anomaly, double precision) {
    static const int MAX_ITERATIONS = 10000;

    double diff = 0.001;
    double e1, e0 = mean_anomaly;
    for(int i = 0; diff > precision && i < MAX_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        e1 = mean_anomaly + eccentricity * sin(e0);

        diff = e1 - e0;
        if(diff < 0) { diff = -diff; }

        e0 = e1;
    }
    return e0;
}

double calculateTrueAnomaly(double eccentricity, double eccentric_anomaly) {
    eccentric_anomaly = tan(eccentric_anomaly / 2);
    eccentricity = sqrt((1 + eccentricity) / (1 - eccentricity));
    return 2 * atan(eccentricity * eccentric_anomaly);
}

int main() {
    // расчет массы марса
    const double MASS = exp(24 * log(0.642) + log(10));
    const double GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT = exp(-11 * log(6.67) + log(10));

    // расчет гравитационного параметра
    double gravitational_parametr;
    gravitational_parametr = MASS * GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT;

    //расчет главной полуоси
    double major_axis;
    major_axis = (APOCENTER_RADIUS_VECTOR + PERIAPSIS_RADIUS_VECTOR) / 2;

    // расчет эксцентриситета 
    double eccentricity;
    eccentricity = (APOCENTER_RADIUS_VECTOR / major_axis) - 1;

    // Расчет фокального параметра
    double focal_parameter;
    focal_parameter = major_axis * (1 - eccentricity * eccentricity);

    // Вывод результата
    std::cout << "а: " << major_axis << '\n';
    std::cout << "e: " << eccentricity << '\n';
    std::cout << "p: " << focal_parameter << '\n';

    std::ofstream fout("result2.txt");
    if(!fout.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "File has not been written!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    const double PRECISION = 1e-10;

    double ma_i = 2 * PI / PERIOD;
    double mean_anomaly = 0, eccentric_anomaly, true_anomaly;

    fout << "0 0\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < PERIOD; ++i) {
        mean_anomaly += ma_i;
        eccentric_anomaly = calculateEccentricAnomaly(eccentricity, mean_anomaly, PRECISION);
        true_anomaly = calculateTrueAnomaly(eccentricity, eccentric_anomaly);

        fout << eccentric_anomaly << " " << true_anomaly << '\n';
    }

    fout.close();
    std::cout << "File has been written!\n";
    return 0;
}
```